# Share avro avdl file to multiple modules

Tags: hadoop, avro

I have a multi-module project. There is a core module that defines some common or generic stuffs. I defined an avdl file in that core module. And I want to define some other avdl files in other modules that use the types defined by the avdl file in core module.

Is there anyway to do that with avro maven plugin?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using maven, you should be able to compile your avdl files using the maven plugin like (from the documentation)

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

if you are expecting the deinifition itself, you should be able to put it as part of the resources in your common project and share it just like one more dependency.